# Angular Development / Apache instead of ng serve

Tags: angular, apache, virtualhost

I am trying to find a way to use apache instead of "ng serve" on my development laptop.
Apache is running perfectly with VirtualHost for Symfony, ExtJs.
I have created a specific VirtualHost for my Angular tests as for the others but I have a white page

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@angulardemo.lan
DocumentRoot "/Users/maquejp/Development/angular/demo/src"
ServerName angulardemo.lan
ServerAlias www.angulardemo.lan
ErrorLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/angulardemo.lan-error_log"
CustomLog "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/angulardemo.lan-access_log" common

<Directory "/Users/maquejp/Development/angular/demo/src">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in addition I have added a .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^app/. /app/index.html [NC,L]
```

Of course I have restarted apache (apachectl -k restart)

For information, I am under OSX.

To avoid wrong response: this is not to deploy on a production server (ng build is not help)

Thanks !

Comment: Nobody has a clue ☹️

Comment: I think you can only use apache to serve built angular pages, normally the dist folder, generated by the `ng dist` command.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to do this?  I'm trying to do the exact same thing, and the lack of information about this makes me wonder if it's a bad idea to serve both the Symfony PHP app and the Angular app using apache rather than separate web servers.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it seems impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `apache2` on a remote Linux host for both development and deployment.  My development path is `~/DEV/ProjectName`.  In my `package.json` file I add the following:

```
"scripts": {
    [snip],
    "watcher": "ng build --base-href=/ProjectName/dist/ProjectName/ --watch",
    [snip]
},
```

I then start the build process `yarn watcher`.

BTW, much of this is found in the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).

The `--watch` flag causes the build process to rerun when a change is made to project files.  `--base-href` builds the URLs to use the path as the base for the index.html file.

I then update my Apache config (`/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/project-dirs.conf`) to look like the following (one for each project):

```
alias /ProjectName /home/homeDir/DEV/ProjectName
<Directory "/home/homeDir/DEV/ProjectName">
    options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Directory>
```

I also add the following `.htaccess` file to fix issues with using routing in my projects.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

This also requires an update to `angular.json` in the `projects\architect\build\options\assest` stanza:

```
"assets": [
    "src/assets/YourIcon.ico",
    "src/assets",
    "src/.htaccess"
]
```

This "should" cause the `.htaccess` file to be placed in the build directory shown above.

One item I have not yet figured out is to how to cause the web page to automatically refresh when build runs.  At the moment a manual refresh is required.